# Posting Form Data to MVC Controller and getting 404 Not Found Error

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, curl

I have a MVC project in C# and in one of my controllers I am accepting HTTP POST data from an outside source and trying to save the file. I have tried many different method signatures but I am having a hell of time figuring out which one to use. I know they don't work because I am getting a 404 error in my IIS logs everytime I try to post to the URL.

A few things I have tried are

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection forms)
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection forms, HttpPostedFileBase files)
public ActionResult Index()
```

I am writing the request out to a failed request log to try and get more insight and I see the headers are:

```
Content-Length: 158293970
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------9228c56ead9fc97c
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: myhostinformationhere
User-Agent: SecurityCenter/5.3.1 (201604012350)
```

Any suggestions?

Some more information I have found. The code posting to my site is php code using curl. Without revealing too much of the vendor source code I see a couple of things they are doing which may help solve the problem. The headers code is

```
$sendHeaders = array ("Except:","X-SecurityCenter: $uuid", "Accept: application/html; charset=utf-8",);
```

They are also adding post fields like this

```
$postFields['reportType'] = $reportType;
$postFields['reportContent'] = curl_file_create($pathInfo['filepath'],$pathInfo['type'],basename($pathInfo['filepath']));
```

I have updated my code to the following but I am getting a timeout error now in my logs

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
  if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
  {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(~/Files/Uploads"), fileName);
    upload.SaveAs(path);
  }

  return View();
}
```

So with the above code I have confirmed with fiddler that a file is captured and uploaded to the correct directory. Now to figure out how to get the post to work from the client software.

Comment: Does the log say which url was not found? It could be an issue with where the request is being sent to.

Comment: Yes the log shows the correct URL being accessed.

Comment: Can you copy paste the URL and access it from a browser? Instead of posting data try hitting the empty index action first. If you get error copy and paste the url in your browser and see what happens.

Comment: Yes I can see the URL just fine if I browse to it from a browser it displays the get index action. The problem is figuring out what type of posted data I need to tell the controller to expect so it routes to this post index

Comment: Ok then clearly the issue is with the way you are calling it. Its late now but if you post the code you are using to call it, I can look at it tomorrow after work.

Comment: I wish I had the calling code :) that would make this so much easier, the code is part of a vendor product and the vendor documentation does not help.

Comment: So when the client hits your URL, MVC is going to look for an action that matches the parameters that are being passed in. You need to match what the client is sending as input params into your controller action. I would get fiddler and make a client call and see what parameters are being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this right you should add another Action in your Controller. You shouldn't use the Index action to try and post data. Try something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save( HttpPostedFileBase file )
{
   if( file != null )
   {
   }

   // Return something to signify success/failure
}
```

Comment: It tried the same thing with any different name it still has the same result. I only used index to quickly throw it together and make sure it works

Comment: Can you post some code as to what you're trying to do? That way I can get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Justin please see above for the php code that posts the form to my site. Note that the calling code is vendor supplied and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try.

Try an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
    // your work...
}
```

Next thing you need to do is to inspect the *Request Body* of the request; this should be in your IIS log. Copy that body and then use Fiddler to create that exact request. [Here](http://www.blogs.progotik.com/using-fiddler-to-make-a-post-request/) is a tutorial on how to make a post request using Fiddler.

In your MVC project's Global.asax.cs file, put the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the HttpApplication's Error event.
/// </summary>
protected void Application_Error() 
{
     // Put a breakpoint here to give you an idea of what is going wrong.
     Exception exception = this.Server.GetLastError();
}
```

You can also use [MVC route debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) to help you out.

In conclusion, keep trying and get it to work with Fiddler with the exact request you are getting from the vendor. Once you have done so, try again with the vendor product.

You can also use Fiddler to capture the request that is coming from the vendor product and inspect the request using that as well.